# Uncaught ReferenceError: addBlogLink is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, html, function

Really frustrated with my self because I know this is simple and I swear my code looks right. I guesse I just need another pair of eyes.

This error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addBlogLink is not defined
```

Gets called on this line of my php code:

```
<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"addBlogLink($userID,'$beerID')\" class = \"btn btn-warning\" name = \"submit\" value=\"Submit Taste Tag\">
```

The problem is, it is defined... If I go to my js page that this function is on I have:

```
function addBlogLink(userID, beerID )
    {
        //get values
        var blogTitle = $('#blogTitle').val();
        var link = $('#blogLink').val();

        //clear div
        $('#textToReplace').empty();

        //call to get new friend list
        $('#textToReplace').load('addBeerBlog.php?u=' + userID + "&b=" + beerID + "&t=" + blogTitle + "&l=" + blogLink,
            function() {

        }); 

        return false;
    }
```

userID is an int and beerID is a string. Also I do have this on my page so I know the js page is able to be contacted:

```
<script src=\"addBlog.js\"></script>
```

Also I know an int and string are being passed because when I look at the page source calling the function I can see this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="addBlogLink(3,'8NX7Sy')" class = "btn btn-warning" name = "submit" value="Submit Taste Tag">
```

Comment: The question is, *where* is it defined? It's clearly out of scope. Is it inside a document.ready handler by any chance? It must be global to be used with inline event handlers.

Comment: I just have a seperate js page with:

function{ }

Comment: Are you sure the javascript source is loading and not a 404, since it is a relative include? You also probably want to clean up the spacing after the class and name attributes.

Comment: If it's inside a script, but not nested inside any other functions, just make sure the external script is linked before your input in the markup. If it's nested, unnest it.

Comment: Ok so I figured out my problem. Thanks for steering me in the right direction. I was using a fancybox iframe and realized I in fact did  not include the call to the js page there. 

I am now getting this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 

on this line: 
var blogTitle = $('#blogTitle').val();

Answer (score 0):

The browser are parsing your HTML tag *INPUT* before it knows that your function *addBlogLink* exists.

I should try something less obstrusive. Like this:

```
<input type="button" id="myID" class = "btn btn-warning" name = "submit" value="Submit Taste Tag">
```

and attach the event in JS:

```
function addBlogLink(userID, beerID ){
   // Your code here
}
document.getElementById("myID").onclick = addBlogLink;
```

Put the SCRIPT tag before </BODY> tag

Answer (score 0):

I made a dumb mistake. I put the:

```
<script src=\"addBlog.js\"></script>
```

In the wrong page. I forgot my fancy box was an iframe not built with my page php class